# All dependencies are not downloaded with "pip download"

Tags: python, pip, package

I'm trying to setup a local directory with packages that can be reused for installation on a machine without an internet connection but I'm having problems with some of the packages.

I first download the packages with

```
pip download -r requirements.txt -d my_packages --no-binary :all:
```

And then I try to install them with

```
pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index -f my_packages
```

One of the packages I'm having trouble installing is `elasticsearch-dsl==6.1.0`:

```
pip install -r requirements --no-index -f my_packages
Looking in links: my_packages
Collecting elasticsearch-dsl==6.1.0
Collecting six (from elasticsearch-dsl==6.1.0)
Collecting python-dateutil (from elasticsearch-dsl==6.1.0)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  Complete output from command /Users/Oskar/.pyenv/versions/2.7.15/envs/no_internet/bin/python2.7 -m pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/36/t0_t6_td2f560t2j0149vjmw0000gn/T/pip-build-env-moib0N --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links my_packages -- setuptools wheel:
  Looking in links: my_packages
  Collecting setuptools
    Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for setuptools
```

Sure, `setuptools` I can manually install but there is more packages than that which is required for all the other packages. `django-guardian==1.4.9` is another example which requires `pytest-runner` which for some reason is not downloaded with `pip download`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `pip wheel`, instead of `pip download`, to pre-download *and compile* your dependencies.

```
$ pip install wheel
$ pip wheel -w my_wheels python-dateutil --no-binary :all:
$ pip install -f my_wheels --no-index python-dateutil    # works
$ pip install -f my_packages --no-index python-dateutil  # breaks
```

`pip wheel` builds the `python-dateutil` package, so you don't need `setuptools_scm` later during `pip install`.

According to the docs,

> Wheel is a built-package format, and offers the advantage of not
>     recompiling your software during every install.

Therefore, I surmise that `pip wheel` will use build-time dependencies, such as `setuptools_scm`, but `pip install` won't, since the `.whl` has been built.

The `--no-binary :all:` option still does the right thing: downloads the source in `.tar.gz` instead of any binary distributions.

(jwodder was shrewd in pointing out the differences between run-time dependencies *i.e.* `install_requires` and build-time dependencies *i.e.* `setup_requires`.)

I tested this on a local environment, and no `setuptools_scm` and no `pytest-runner`, no problem.

```
(py3) j@computer:~/so-examples|⇒ pip freeze
django-guardian==1.4.9
python-dateutil==2.7.3
six==1.11.0
```

Comment: Works great until you want something that is cross-platform :)

Answer (score 8):

Because you specified `--no-binary :all:`, pip only downloads sdists for the packages and does not download any wheels.  However, pip still needs each package in wheel form when it comes time to install, and so `pip install` tries to build a wheel for each package from the sdist, and this step requires `setuptools`, `wheel`, and anything listed in the package's `setup_requires`.  I don't know why your environment doesn't have `setuptools`, but any healthy Python environment should have both it and `wheel` installed when the environment is created.

Unfortunately for you, packages listed in `setup_requires` are installed by `setuptools` itself rather than by pip, so `pip download` has no way to capture these requirements.  If you insist on using `--no-binary :all:`, then the only solution is to manually compile a list of packages that are missing when `pip install` runs, download them, and then either install the missing packages before the ones that depend on them or else [configure setuptools to look for the downloads in `my_packages`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#controlling-setup-requires).  Fortunately, the list will likely be rather short (probably just `pytest-runner` and `setuptools_scm`).

Comment: _However, pip still needs each package in wheel form when it comes time to install, and so pip install tries to build a wheel for each package from the sdist_ - that's not true. `pip install pkgname --no-binary=pkgname` will skip `bdist_wheel` and invoke `setup.py install` instead.

Comment: Other than that, I agree this is the most reasonable approach. To collect all build dependencies, a complex solution is needed, including unpacking source dists, running `setup.py egg_info` in each unpacked dir and collecting the list of build deps from the `.eggs` dir. Most probably this should be also repeated recursively for each build dependency, since eggs are also binary dists; too much unnecessary overhead for a one-time task that also can/should be replaced with collecting wheels instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pip2pi](https://github.com/wolever/pip2pi/) to avoid reinventing the wheel, this is a very handy tool for creating your own pip repos. I maintain a partial pypi mirror for my team and had the best results with this project.

From its Github page: "pip2pi builds a PyPI-compatible package repository from pip requirements"

```
$ pip install pip2pi
$ mkdir packages
$ pip2tgz packages/ -r requirements.txt
$ dir2pi -n packages/ # <--- this builds/updates the index, i.e. the "simple/" directory
```

Now just serve the packages/simple/ folder through http and use it as your index.

```
$ pip install -i http://myserver.net/simple/ -r requirements.txt
```

To avoid the hassle of pip security check you can tune your pip.conf like this:

```
[global]
format=columns
disable_pip_version_check = 1
index-url=file:http://myserver.net/simple/
```

Now you can install from your own mirror with the regular `pip install` command.