# distribution package for pyautogui and openpyxl

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to install pyautogui, openpyxl with Python in a machine which does not connect to internet. Is there a distribution package of python which can do this?

Comment: Which command are you using to install this package? pip?

Comment: I observed that for installing using pip 'internet' connectivity is required so that libraries are downloaded. But my system cannot have internet connectivity, it is a standalone system where in I need run Python scripts. So in this case I do not use pip.

Comment: of course I can get the packages downloaded from another system connected to internet and copy to. So what is the clean way to do this type of install? Is there a distribution package like ANACONDA which can have all this including pyautogui and openpyxl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following steps worked for me successfully -

1. Dowload Anconda 3 package in a system where internet connection is there.
2. Download pyautogui.tar.bz2 using "pip download pytuatogui".
3. Copy both to a system where internet connection is not there.
4. Install Anacoda 3 manually.
5. Install the pyuaotgui.tar.bz2 using command 
   "conda install /path/to/local/file/.tar.bz2

Then things started working properly in a system where internet connection was not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pip for that. However, you need a computer *with* internet connection (and python installed) to download the required packages first:

On the computer *with* internet connection, open a command line and say

```sh
pip download pyautogui openpyxl
```

Copy all downloaded files to the target machine, then install with

```sh
pip install ...
```

Where `...` means *all* downloaded files. It is important to put them all in one line. So, all dependencies can be resolved (otherwise you need to take care to install the dependencies first).

Comment: I did as you suggested. I am getting an error during installation of 'pygetwindow 0.0.5' the error says "Type error: 'encoding' is an invalid argument for this function.

Comment: Hmm, I can't help for this specific error. I just described the procedure I have successfully applied to install Python packages on machines having no access to the internet.

Comment: Do you have the same version of Python on both machines? Could be a Python2/Python3 issue.

Comment: [All dependencies are not downloaded with “pip download”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51748058/2311167) could be helpful too.

Comment: [About offline installation of pyautogui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56437721/getting-error-typeerror-encoding-is-an-invalid-keyword-argument-for-this-fun) My problem was also resolved by helpful comments after following your suggestions @AdrianW

Comment: If it was helpful, you may want to accept and upvote the answer. This is the way to that "thanks" in SO ;-)

Comment: I did that just now. I am new to stackoverflow.