# Getting error "TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function" during pyautogui installation

Tags: python

I wanted to install `pyautogui, openpyxl` with Python in a machine which does not have connectivity to internet.

On a computer with internet connection, I opened command line and executed below command.

```
pip download pyautogui openpyxl
```

Copied all downloaded files to the target machine, then installed with

```
pip install ...
```

Where... means all downloaded files.  all in one line.

I get error as following while doing this -

```
with open('README.md', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function


 C:\Temp\DSNImport>cd "C:\Temp\DSNImport\picu\python libraries"
      C:\Temp\DSNImport\picu\python libraries>pip install openpyxl-2.6.2.tar.gz PyAutoGUI-0.9.44.tar.gz et_xmlfile-1.0.1.tar.gz jdcal-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl Pillow-6.0.0.tar.gz PyGetWindow-0.0.5.tar.gz PyRect-0.1.4.tar.gz PyScreeze-0.1.21.tar.gz
    Processing c:\temp\dsnimport\picu\python libraries\openpyxl-2.6.2.tar.gz
    Processing c:\temp\dsnimport\picu\python libraries\pyautogui-0.9.44.tar.gz
    Processing c:\temp\dsnimport\picu\python libraries\et_xmlfile-1.0.1.tar.gz
      Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): et-xmlfile==1.0.1 from file:///C:/Temp/DSNImport/picu/python%20libraries/et_xmlfile-1.0.1.tar.gz in c:\programdata\anaconda2\lib\site-packages
    Processing c:\temp\dsnimport\picu\python libraries\pillow-6.0.0.tar.gz
    Processing c:\temp\dsnimport\picu\python libraries\pygetwindow-0.0.5.tar.gz
        Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "c:\users\superu~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-bbamct-build\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
            with open('README.md', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
        TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
       ----------------------------------------   Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\superu~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-bbamct-build\
       C:\Temp\DSNImport\picu\python libraries>
```

How to get 'pyautogui' installed?

Comment: Install anaconda3

Comment: What you want? you say you are getting an error and sometime you say you want something to get installed. Clear with your thoughts please.

Comment: I get error when I do the installation as per the steps I had described. So wanted to know how to overcome the error. Or if not possible to correct the error, then what is the right way to do this installation.

Comment: @SmartManoj does anaconda3 package contain 'pyautogui' as well as 'openpyxl' libraries?

Comment: @SanoopkrishnanSunil Yes they have

Comment: @SmartManoj I installed Anaconda3 2019 for Windows. But it does not have 'pyautogui' library. Is there any other distribution package which contains pyautogui?

Comment: Its there https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyautogui. What do you get when install

Comment: @SmartManoj I installed 'Anaconda 3' in a machine which is not connected to internet. The installation completes successfully. But I don't see any additional libraries installed along with it. After installation when I try to execute my script containing pyautogui functions the execution fails mentioning the pyautogui libraries missing. Do I need to install "anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyautogui" separately? Does it need internet connectivity?

Comment: Install manually `conda install -c conda-forge pyautogui `

Comment: Is internet connectivity required for doing this install?     conda install -c conda-forge pyautogui

Comment: @SmartManoj Is internet connectivity required for doing this install? conda install -c conda-forge pyautogui –

Comment: @SmartManoj   Thanks a lot. This worked for me "conda install /path/to/local/file/<package-file-name>.tar.bz2 "