# How do I install Pytorch offline?

Tags: python, pytorch

I need to install Pytorch on a computer with no internet connection.

I've tried finding information about this online but can't find a single piece of documentation.

Do you know how I can do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: You can [download the wheels](https://pypi.org/project/torch/#files) from pypi and use pip to install from the files directly (gonna have to do the same for all dependencies I suppose).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All dependencies are not downloaded with "pip download"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748058/all-dependencies-are-not-downloaded-with-pip-download)

Answer (score 13):

An easy way with *pip*:

- Create an empty folder
- `pip download torch` using the connected computer. You'll get the pytorch package and all its dependencies.
- Copy the folder to the offline computer. You must be using the same python setup on both computers (this goes for virtual environments as well)
- `pip install *` on the offline computer, in the copied folder. This installs all the packages in the correct order. You can then use pytorch.

Note that this works for (almost) any kind of python package.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Hadn't thought to look up how to do this in general with Python packages instead of specifically with Pytorch. Will try tomorrow and accept the answer if it works :)

Comment: For python version 3.8 (current) pip version 19.2.3  "pip install *" , did not work. When I tried installing by specifying file name after each pip install command, I was not able to install pytorch.

Answer (score -1):

Download source of pytorch from https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch

Then follow the tutorial named:
Install PyTorch